# Complex search program

Tags: c#, performance, xml, search

I am working on a fairly complex (at least it feels complex to me at the moment) search program and am looking to possibly increase the performance. Everything works exactly how I want it to, but I'm just wondering if there are any slight performance increases I could benefit from. In this code, *even minor performance increases are essential*.  This is due to the extensive amount of operations being performed.

```
// Split search into multiple terms and check the {x} longest terms against the cache.
string[] word = searchTerm.Split(' ');
Array.Sort(word, (x, y) => y.Length.CompareTo(x.Length));
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    string searchValue = word[i];
    if (i <= MAX_WORD_ITERATIONS && (xmlsearchResults == BLANK_SEARCH_XML_SCHEMA || xmlsearchResults == string.Empty))
    {
        xmlsearchResults = GetCachedRecord(thisSearch, searchValue);
    }
    if (xmlsearchResults != BLANK_SEARCH_XML_SCHEMA && xmlsearchResults != string.Empty)
    {
        thisSearch.Value = searchValue;
        ignoreCache = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

```
xmlString.Append(string.Format(@"<{0}>", xmlHeader));
int objcount = 0;
string prevResultName = string.Empty;
try
{
    if (searchResults.hitCount > 0)
    {
        List<SearchItem> SearchResults = new List<SearchItem>();
        foreach (Node ResultNode in Results.Nodes)
        {
            string code = ResultNode.code.ToString();
            string result = ResultNode.id.ToString();
            string name = ResultNode.name_l.ToString();
            string image = string.Empty;

            if (!code.ToLower().Contains("ccb") && code.Length <= MAX_CODE_LENGTH &&
                name != prevResultName && objcount < maxResults)
            {
                Boolean addResult = true;
                if (thisSearch.FilterDescription)
                {
                    if (!name.ToLower().Contains(thisSearch.Value.ToLower()))
                    {
                        addResult = false;
                    }
                }
                if (addResult)
                {
                    SearchItem oSearch = new SearchItem(name, code);
                    SearchResults.Add(oSearch);
                    prevResultName = name;
                }
            }
        }
        var SortedSearchResults = SearchResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.Downloads).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < SortedSearchResults.Count(); i++)
        {
            if ((objcount < maxResults))
            {
                string te = string.Format("<ResultName>{0}</ResultName>", SortedSearchResults[i].Description);
                if (!xmlString.ToString().Contains(te))
                {
                    xmlString.Append(SortedSearchResults[i].GetXMLString());
                    objcount += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
xmlString.Append(string.Format(@"</{0}>", xmlHeader));
return objcount;
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. Can you please at least tell us the types of all the identifiers you use?

Answer (score 8):

Comparing strings case insensitively is done by using the proper overload:

```
string.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

By calling `.ToLower()` for each string to compare (4 times for each iteration), you create 4 new strings each time. If you have a lot of (long) strings, this will create a lot of garbage for no reason.

In your case you use `.Contains()` so you can mimic this by using `.IndexOf()`:

```
str4.IndexOf("dyt2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

---

It's prettier to use `bool` instead of `Boolean`, partly because it also keeps your code consistent.

---

Write your variable names in full: `objectCount`, `previousResultName`, etc.

---

Constants are `PascalCase`, not `WHATEVER_THIS_IS` as in Java.

---

The `addResult` variable seems a little wonky. Instead of this:

```
Boolean addResult = true;
if (thisSearch.FilterDescription)
{
    if (!name.ToLower().Contains(thisSearch.Value.ToLower()))
    {
        addResult = false;
    }
}
if (addResult)
{
    SearchItem oSearch = new SearchItem(name, code);
    SearchResults.Add(oSearch);
    prevResultName = name;
}
```

Why not this:

```
if (!(thisSearch.FilterDescription && !name.ToLower().Contains(thisSearch.Value.ToLower()))
{
    SearchItem oSearch = new SearchItem(name, code);
    SearchResults.Add(oSearch);
    prevResultName = name;
}
```

You can clean this up a bit more but I'm not in a boolean algebra mood.

Comment: Okay thanks, so for the `.ToLower().Contains(...` it should just be `string.Compare(code, "ccd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was a .Contains call. In that case use `.IndexOf()` with the appropriate overload. I'll edit it.

Comment: Okay, so I would actually want `<`, right? Because it's a `Not` operation.

Comment: @Volearix: correct.

Comment: THIS_IS_SNAKE_CASE! \*Kicks you into well\*

Comment: There is a case insensitive contains somewhere in the globalization namespace

Answer (score 6):

One way to improve performance would be to not sort the whole list, since you're only concerned about the `MAX_WORD_ITERATIONS` longest items. Just do a partial sort.

At the very least, limit your `for` loop to only going `MAX_WORD_ITERATIONS` times. If it's not found by then, it won't be found.

It looks like the first `if` serves no purpose and can be eliminated.

## Code segment 1

```
Array.PartialSort(word, (x, y) => y.Length.CompareTo(x.Length),MAX_WORD);
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_WORD_ITERATIONS; i++)
{
    string searchValue = word[i];
    xmlsearchResults = GetCachedRecord(thisSearch, searchValue);
    if (xmlsearchResults != BLANK_SEARCH_XML_SCHEMA && xmlsearchResults != string.Empty)
    {
        thisSearch.Value = searchValue;
        ignoreCache = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

## Code segment 2

```
xmlString.Append(string.Format(@"<{0}>", xmlHeader));
```

[How about using `AppendFormat()`?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  No speed increase but easier-to-read code.

```
if (!code.ToLower().Contains("ccb")
```

Instead of creating a temporary lowercase string, just use the case-insensitive compare:

```
code.IndexOf("ccb", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

```
    var SortedSearchResults = SearchResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.Downloads).ToList();
```

Why are you converting it to a `List<>`? You're not doing anything that requires a `List<>`. Leave it as an `IEnumerable<>` and use a `foreach` to iterate over it.

Answer (score 5):

One thing which might improve performance:

I'm not sure what `xmlString` is but given how it's used it's probably a `StringBuilder`. What you do in this loop:

> ```
>    for (int i = 0; i < SortedSearchResults.Count(); i++)
>     {
>         if ((objcount < maxResults))
>         {
>             string te = string.Format("<ResultName>{0}</ResultName>", SortedSearchResults[i].Description);
>             if (!xmlString.ToString().Contains(te))
>             {
>                 xmlString.Append(SortedSearchResults[i].GetXMLString());
>                 objcount += 1;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

is that you convert the content of the `StringBuilder` into a `string` then do a string search on it (`Contains()`) and then append if it's no already present. So for every result you have to search through all previous results in the end making this an an `O(n^2)` operation. Using a `Distinct` filter should reduce the complexity to `O(n)`. LINQ doesn't provide a `Distinct` for a specific property but it's easy to write a [little extension method (courtesy of SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

`HashSet<>` has `O(1)` lookup hence this filter is `O(n)`.

Then your loop becomes:

```
    var objCount = 0;
    foreach (var result in SortedSearchResults.DistinctBy(r => r.Description).Take(maxResults))
    {
        xmlString.Append(result.GetXMLString());
        ++objCount;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't just say "An O(1) algorithm is better" unless you know the constant factors and the sample size. An O(log n) or O(n) algorithm with a smaller constant factor may be superior for this use case.

Comment: @Snowbody: Hm, reading the answer I can't see where I just said "An O(1) algorithm is better". My answer says "It might be better to turn an O(n^2) algorithm into an O(n) algorithm by the use of a different data structure". Since the OP stated even minor performance improvements are important I'd say it's certainly worth a shot.